# CSS slideshow does not properly show images first time on website

Tags: html, css

I am the webmaster of [The Cast](http://www.thecast.nl/), a Dutch musical group. I did not develop the site, I just keep it updated. I only have just enough HTML knowledge to do this.
Lately the slideshow on the front page has some issues, in some browsers on some systems* the first time you open the site the images only show in a 7 by 18 pixel rectangle. Then when you navigate to the home page from inside the site it works correctly and when you refresh it, it goes wrong again. I really hope someone can help me with it.

HTML CODE:

```
   <!-- slideshow -->
            <div id="slideshow">
                <ul id="slides">
                    <li><img src="slides/01.jpg"  alt="Imagen" /></li>
                    <li><img src="slides/02.jpg"  alt="Imagen" /></li>
                    <li><img src="slides/03.jpg"  alt="Imagen" /></li>
                    <li><img src="slides/04.jpg"  alt="Imagen" /></li>
                </ul>
                <span></span>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/prev-slide.png"  alt="Prev" id="prev" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/next-slide.png"  alt="Next" id="next" /></a>
            </div>
            <!-- ENDS slideshow -->
```

CSS code. (everything to do with slides).

```
div#slideshow{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 380px;
    width: 960px;
}

div#slideshow ul#slides{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 380px;
    position: absolute;
}

div#slideshow ul#slides img{
    border-radius:15px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 380px;

}

div#slideshow-arrows{
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 57px;
}    

div#slideshow img#prev{
    position: absolute;
    top:180px;
    left: 1px;
    z-index: 20;
}

div#slideshow img#next{
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    right: 1px;
    z-index: 21;
}    

div#slideshow span{
    border-radius:15px;
    border:3px solid white;
    width: 954px;
    height: 374px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#slideshow-nav{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 18px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#slideshow-nav a { 
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(../img/slidebutton.png) no-repeat; 
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#slideshow-nav a.activeSlide { 
    background: url(../img/slidebutton-over.png) no-repeat; 
}    

div.fade-slide{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 345px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

*(Issue reported on Mac OS(not sure which version) in Safari, on Windows 7 in Chrome and Firefox and another on Windows 7 in Chrome)

Comment: Is there JavaScript controlling the slideshow? I suspect that's where the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this css style at style.css at 480 line.

```
div#slideshow ul#slides {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px !important;
    height: 380px !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```